# Updating a DynamoDB item with a new attribute that's a list

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

So I have an item in DynamoDB:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

And I want to add a new attribute to said item, the attribute being:

```
{
  "newAttr": [{ "bar": 1 }, { "bar": 2 }, { "bar": 3 }]
}
```

Now I'm doing this in JS using the AWS-SDK like so:

```
client.update({
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#newAttr': 'newAttr' },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':newAttr': newAttr },
  Key: { "id": "1" },
  TableName: "foo",
  UpdateExpression: "SET #newAttr = :newAttr"
}, callback)
```

However, I get an error:

> ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid value: One or more
>   parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an
>   empty string for key :newAttr

So if I were to `JSON.stringify(newAttr)` then it's fine, but I don't want this new attribute to be a string, I want it to be a list.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Try ADD instead of SET

```
    client.update({
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#newAttr': 'newAttr' },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':newAttr': newAttr },
  Key: { "id": "1" },
  TableName: "foo",
  UpdateExpression: "ADD #newAttr = :newAttr"
}, callback)
```

I ended up having these issues in the beginning. I'm sure you are wasting time in writing in all the low-level code to interact with DynamoDB.

Use an ODM (ORM Like) for document storage which handles all the hurdles for you.

https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels

is what I have used and will make your life much easier.

> Empty String are not allowed

One cannot store empty strings with DynamoDB at the root level. You can have it in the nested objects.

Allowed Data Types from DynamoDB:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. It turned out to be a problem with the object having empty string values much further down. Thanks for the ODM suggestion, I shall certainly look at it and see if it can facilitate the pain of empty strings.